# I want to get the result of all Candidates but only the first one comes

Tags: java, jdbc

How do I get a full list of all candidates for example `positionName` should print all the first names
This my DAO

```
public Candidate CandTable(String positionName) {
    Candidate cand = null;
    try {  
        Connection con = SQLConnection.connect();
        String query = "select * from candidate where positionName=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, positionName);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            cand=new Candidate();
            cand.setStudentID(rs.getString("StudentID"));
            cand.setEncodedImage(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rs.getBytes("image")));
            cand.setFirstName(rs.getString("fName"));
            cand.setLastName(rs.getString("lName"));
            cand.setClassName(rs.getString("className"));
            cand.setPostionName(rs.getString("positionName"));
            cand.setSex(rs.getString("sex"));
            cand.setDob(rs.getDate("dob"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cand;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the only the first one comes.  I am thinking that only the last one comes.  I your code `cand=new Candidate();` you are creating anew object for each loop, but you are not adding it to a List (or array) and then you return that last Object `return cand;`

Comment: True the last one comes

Comment: How do I add to array

Comment: well you want your code to return a `List<Candidate>`, try it and let us know when/if you get stuck.

Comment: I have done it thanks

Comment: How do I give you thumbs up 

Comment: You just did. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

After using arrayList I was able to get all the values successfully

```
public List<Candidate> CandTable(Candidate cand) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
     Connection con = SQLConnection.connect();
//      Candidate cand = null;
     List<Candidate> CT = new ArrayList();
```